# Projection of Range of Matrix $ A $ onto Kernel of $ A-I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let A be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $A^2 = A$.

Show that $Ax = x$ for every $x$ in $R(A)$ and if $rank(A)$ $= 1$, $M = R(A)$, $N = Ker(A-I)$ then $A $ is the projection along $N$ onto $M$.

For the first part, I said that $A^2 * x = A * x $ so multiplying by $A^{-1}$ on both sides we have $A * x = x$. This doesn't sound right because I am assuming $A$ is invertible.

The second part, I get the feeling that $M$ and $N$ are two lines that pass through the origin. I don't understand how to find the projection matrix that projects $N$ onto $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints.

For the first part, you can indeed not assume that $A$ is invertible. However you haven't used the fact that $x\in R(A)$.

For the second part you seem confused about what it means that $A$ is the projection along $N$ on $M$. It graphical terms it means that it takes a point and then slides it parallel to $N$ until it hits $M$. In algebraic terms it means that for every $x\in\mathbb R^2$ there are unique $m\in M$ and $n\in N$ such that $x=m+n$ and $Ax=m$.

However I think your question might contain an error since $N=M$ as defined.

Comment: How are N and M equal, if you don't mind explaining. @Jorik

Comment: @YunusSyed Giving it away fully would kinda spoil the first part, but I'll give a further hint. $\ker(A-I) = \{x\in\mathbb R^2\mid (A-I)x=0\}$. But $(A-I)x = Ax-x$. So $N$ is all $x$ such that $Ax=x$. This already shows that $N\subseteq M$. I believe the correct $N$ would be $\ker(A)$ instead.

Comment: You may be right but we know from part A any x in range also satisfies x is in M

Comment: So N and M are equal

Comment: @YunusSyed Yes that is in fact the definition of $M$. The first part boils down to the other inclusion, $M\subseteq N$.

Comment: What exactly does A do in this case? Does it just project a line onto itself?

Comment: No it projects all the points in the plane onto the line $M$. Perhaps an example would help. If $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ then $A^2=A$. You can easily compute that $A(x,y) = (x,0)$. So what $A$ does is project every point $(x,y)$ straight up or down onto the $x$-axis. So we say that $A$ is the projection on the $x$-axis along the $y$-axis.

Comment: So for N, then the projection A just projects N onto M which is itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32878/discussion-between-jorik-and-yunus-syed).